# Text appearing stacked in page pseudo CSS3/HTML5

Tags: html, css

I'm making a web page for a charity and the text on the page is appearing stacked without my intention. I decided to play around with CSS3 and HTML5 (badly) so it won't be fully compliant.

I've tried searching and looked at some articles about how to stack with css3 but it doesn't seem that I've accidently implemented any of these by accident. It's in PHP for no other reason than to use 'include' and because I plan on expanding it so all the html and css you can see on the page is all that's going on.

The footer is appearing behind the main body of text.

http://aberystwythslsc.org/activities.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to ask here. Also your grammar is incredibly confusing. Please clearify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<section>` has a set height.  Simply remove that and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks that was driving me insane!

Comment: @user1680289 by the way you can hide overflowing content with `overflow: hidden` or more specifically in this case `overflow-y: hidden`, or add a scroll bar if it's over with `overflow: auto`.  However, I think you want this content to be visible.